# Receiving this error while doing performance testing via Jmeter for mobile app.**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

Tags: jmeter

I am testing performance of mobile app via jmeter for android mobile app. FOr most of the apps installed in my mobile device, I am receiving below error message.
Software caused connection abort: recv failed
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**.
Please help me to know how to resolve this error, while testing with mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Well have you done what the error message says e.g. have you installed the JMeter CA certificate ? look at this guide and check if you have followed the steps correctly [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder] (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) especially this step :

> 13. Return to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, and click the “Start” button at the bottom.
>       This will start the JMeter proxy server which is used to intercept the browser requests.
>       A file called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt will be generated in jmeter/bin folder.
>       Install this certificate in your browser, if you don't know how to do it, read “
>       Installing the
>       JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording
>       ” in : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Answer (score 0):

When you start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder it generates a dummy certificate in order to be able to decrypt SSL traffic.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in JMeter's /bin folder (it may live in other location if you run JMeter i.e. from desktop shortcut)
2. Install it onto your device (the easiest way is sending it to yourself via email, open the email on device and click on the attachment)
3. After certificate installation device should be

You may find [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service easier to use

Comment: In this does this mean that the machine that is acting as proxy server on that the certificates should be installed. i am actually looking for mobile app performance testing and not for the web app.

Comment: The same certificate needs to be installed on JMeter and Mobile Device, otherwise you won't be able to record secure mobile traffic

Comment: I have installed same certificate in Macbook and iPhone and made those as "Truested" But still I'm getting "ensure browser is set to accept the jmeter proxy certificate" in Jmeter. To Access the services which deployed in Windows server, my Macbook connected to VPN (There is no VPN in iPhone because it is not needed I guess) Same error getting for Android device as well. The test App develop using Xamarin Forms.How do I resolve this issue?